# iPad form disable [previous | next] buttons

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, html, mobile-safari

So I have a form wizard that exists in a slider. The whole idea is to gate people based on their decisions. The problem is the ipad. On the iPad it allows you to hit [previous|next] to move through fields on the form, and this breaks the gating strategy.

On desktop browsers I suppressed the `TAB` key by returning false on keypress on gated fields. But on the iPad I see no solution.

I've tried tabindex and set gated inputs to -1. The problem here is that after they move through the gate the [previous|next] buttons reactive and mess everything up.

Is there a way I can remove those buttons all together? Or capture them as a js event?

(NOTE this is a mobile web page, not an app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was to `disable` and set `visibility: hidden` on any form elements that the user should not be able to tab to. This is a pain in the ass, but it works well on iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [touch-input-nav.js](https://github.com/ChrisWren/touch-input-nav) to automatically disable input fields that aren't contained in the same form as the control that currently has focus.  This is essentially an automated way of doing Ben's solution.  Found via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20943185/71262).

Answer (score 0):

You can capture onfocus and onblur events of your various elements, and have some logic decide if allowed or not, depending on your needs. The result would be pressing "Next" and remaining in place.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I ended up doing, but it makes for a bad UX.

Comment: Well, the buttons cannot be removed, they are there always in the keyboard window shown by Safari. It is pretty hackish to remove them even in a UIWebView in iOS apps.

Perhaps you could put each field in its own form, which might confuse the next/previous and disable them.

Comment: I tried that too :( and unfortunately an app is out of the question.

Comment: I meant, put each HTML element in a separate HTML form.